# error while using delete query in spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [delete from users where name=sds3]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "SDS3": invalid identifier

Comment: public int deleteuser(String user_name)
{
  String f="delete from users  where name="+user_name+"";  
     return template.update(f);  
 
 
}

Comment: do you probably miss the " around your SDS3?

Answer (score 1):

The correct query would be

```
delete from users where name = 'sds3'
```

Note the quotes around the string value.

You need to learn [using prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), which would avoid that bug, work fine even if the value contains a quote, and prevent [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "delete from users where name = ?");
stmt.setString(1, userName);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Note that the Spring JDBC template does use prepared statements, and that NamedParameterJdbcTemplate also supports named parameters. You should use that.